# Protecting MCU digital input with 300m wires

Tags: digital-logic, protection, gpio, esd

I need to protect the inputs and a 3.3V MCU (ESP32) from damage (eg lightning) and noise with a switch connected at the end of a cable that can be hundreds of meters long.

Based on the schematic (Fig 13) here [Digikey - Protecting Inputs](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/protecting-inputs-in-digital-electronics) I have the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4EFIR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- R3 is a 0.5W resistor, D2 is a Schottky diode
- The switch is a manual push switch, or relay contact. I cannot add anything at this end of the circuit (ie, no capacitor across the switch contacts etc)
- The 300m cable would ideally be a shielded twisted pair, but this is outside my control and may just be 2 separate wires
- Would dropping the voltage to the switch down to 5V provide the same level of noise immunity?

I'd welcome any input on anything that could be done to improve this design. Are there advantages to switching a GND rather than the 24V (the other circuits on the Digikey guide all switch the GND line)

Comment: I'd normally arrange R2/3 to form a voltage divider to bring the expected input voltage down to 3V3. Size it so that 20mA flows through the switch For D1, rather than a zener, I'd use a transzorb to take care of transients. in normal operation it wouldn't activate. It also pays to do some filtering/debouncing in software to ensure you respond to valid inputs rather than transients.

Comment: Nothing protects against lightning, only mitigates. Anything is better than nothing, and both Digikey's and Kartman's suggestions are much better than nothing. A small fast-blow fuse in each outgoing line would improve lightning hardness, and while an optocoupler might be seen by some as paranoid, it will survive closer strikes (but still not a direct strike on the switch) than a direct connection.

Comment: Very important question. Will the switch spend long periods closed, for instance if it's water level float switch in a borehole? Or is it a manual pushbutton that will spend practically no time closed? If the latter, an isolated battery driving the switch line will have essentially its storage life, and makes practical an optocoupler with the switch totally galvanically (big 8 mm air-gap) isolated from the MCU its power supply.

Comment: A direct lightning hit does significant physical damage, but the usual effect of lightning is from a close strike. Depending on the environment, an earth lift (where the earth between two points gets a voltage gradient due to the strike, magnetic, where wiring forms the secondary of a transformer and gets a high current pulse induced into it or capacitive where the air forms the dielectric between the strike and your wiring. I've had installations where even a 10kV rated opto did nothing as a critical grounding wire was omitted.

Answer (score 2):

I would ground one end of the switch instead of connecting it to +24V. That way if the wires short to ground, it won't short the 24V supply.

[image]

Then a diode to protect against reverse voltage, and a BJT that can accept any kind of input voltage as long as it turns on. That way there is no need to limit the input voltage to 3V3.

Comment: you need sufficient current to 'wet' the contacts of a mechanical switch.

Comment: Yes, R4-C1 provide a current spike when it switches on. R3 shouldn't be too low.

Comment: You've not done CE immunity testing then. The fast transient test is the downfall of many.

Comment: OK, tell me what will go wrong re immunity

Comment: Due to the transistor, the trip voltage is low - down around 0.7V and you don’t need much current. With a cmos input its at half VCC. Providing a greater load requires more energy to change the input state. Thus better immunity.

Comment: Damn, you're right! I looked back in altium and found the resistor I had forgotten about (R5) when drawing the schematic for the post from memory ;)

Comment: This is an input to a MCU, so false triggering should never be an issue unless he's trying to catch a submillisecond pulse. I've never seen EMI that can keep a GPIO high for 10's of milliseconds (barring an actual fault).

Answer (score 1):

Noise immunity shouldn't be an issue if the switch will be activated for more than a fraction of a second at a time. Just use some software filtering.

The next issue is the wires acting as antennas. I would add some 0.1uF caps to ground from each lead to spoil that.

I would simplify the rest of the circuit by using an optocoupler with a zenner diode for over voltage protection. But your approach may also work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting a direct lightning strike, then there's nothing you can do, without some serious hardware.

If the lightning you are talking of is a local strike, you can get a lot of current induced in the loop of wires, which you can mitigate by twisting them together, as you noted. But you will always have some current induced.

You'll also have noise current induced in the wires from other sources, like radio and capacitively coupled mains.

Much of the noise current you can expect will be too small to result in voltages that would trigger a TVS, or Zener diode, but may still be significant enough to trigger or damage the digital input. So, some of your mitigating measures will be concerned with small currents, and some with larger ones.

Your aim is to minimise the effect of induced currents, which are inevitable, and this is done by reducing the loop's impedance. It makes sense because any voltages that are developed due to those currents are subject to Ohm's law \$V=I \times R\$. Smaller \$R\$, smaller \$V\$.

Some loop current is deliberate, caused by the closure of the switch, and you should aim to make this as large as possible, large compared to noise current, so you may distinguish it from noise. Obviously, you are concerned with keeping power usage reasonable, and what's acceptable depends on many things, such as battery longevity, or power supply capability.

If you have any experience with 4-20 mA sensors and equipment, you'll be aware that they employ a current loop, in which 4 mA is considered to be significant compared to induced noise current, which is inevitable in long(ish) cables in an industrial environment. Perhaps, in your application, you can aim for something of that order, say 10 mA, in your current loop.

Your current loop could be as simple as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2falot1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage across R1 will still be 24 V or 0 V, depending on switch position, but now a lot of current is required to produce that change, and the environment will have to work hard to compete with the 10 mA that flows when the switch is closed.

The first line of defense should be a TVS. The aim is to absorb as much energy as possible from large spikes, but it is not concerned with the well-being of more sensitive elements following it. Although you *could* use a TVS to clamp input voltages to digital signal levels, I'd rather use it to clamp "coarsely". Cheaper, low power devices, further along the signal path, can take care of fine-level clamping.

Since our signal source is the voltage across R1, that's where we clamp with a TVS, right across it. The TVS voltage rating needs to be greater than 24 V, since we don't want it clamping innocent, deliberate signals. We can also suppress radio frequency noise with a capacitor C1 across R1, and perhaps (optionally) an RF choke L1 (see below).

We have a 24/0 V signal, from which we require very little current, since the MCU input needs hardly any. From here on in, our focus is level translation to 3.3/0 V, which can be achieved with a resistor potential divider, in the ratio 6.3:1. Following the divider, we can perform additional clamping, but this time it's at a low current, and we can use low power devices.

We can also perform further filtering, to suppress sensitivity to switch noise/bounce and other short-duration (less than 10 ms) transients that get through. So far we have this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftSimx.png)</sup>

The TVS clamps to ±36 V, so following the potential divider formed by R2 and R3, we can expect at worst ±5 V. That 5 V source, though, has an impedance of about 3 kΩ. Short circuit current (caused by clamping) will  be at worst \$I = \frac{5}{3000} = 1.7\text{ mA}\$.

It's probable that your microcontroller input's own protection diodes can perform clamping, if they can tolerate a couple of milliamps of current, but if not, or just in case, you can of course do it yourself, using whatever technique you prefer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvbXcZ.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9blxf.png)</sup>

It's hard to beat opto-isolation for protection. If you want to improve your MCU's chances of surviving a really hard spike, then take a look at this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFwP7w.png)</sup>

The 4N25 is a jellybean optoisolator. For ultimate protection, you can use a separate 24 V source, with its own ground, completely isolated from the MCU's power supply. You could still join the grounds together, but you lose a degree of protection.

Due to the additional current path via R2 and the LED, I've increased R1, to keep the total loop current in the vicinity of 10 mA when the switch is closed. I've chosen here to have about 5 mA through R1, and 5mA through the LED.

Since the MCU signal is derived from the +3.3 V supply, there's no clamping necessary following the opto-isolator. As before, C2 is filtering out everything over about 100 Hz.

Note that the state of switch SW1 is inverted, mean that the MCU input is high when the switch is open.

Answer (score 0):

Use an optocoupler for better protection
[image]